# Clusters of Same Size?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-statistics, clustering

I am attempting to use the Grouping Analysis tool in the Spatial Statistics (in ArcGIS 10.2)  to group state high schools (points) together based on enrollment and location.  Is there a way to make each cluster the same size?  I am able to set how many groups I want, but I cannot seem to make each the same size.

Comment: Your question is the same as [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131841/divide-polygons-into-n-number-of-groups-of-equal-counts-with-arcgis-10-2/132218#132218) question but asked differently.