# how to make clusters from small polygons with constraint of boundary touching?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, clustering

I want to make  some clusters from a bunch of  small polygons  with the constraint that each basic unit (polygon) in the resultant cluster must share a portion of its boundary  with at least one other basic unit (polygon) in the same cluster. This is becuase of the reason that i want the resultant clusters contagious.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131841/divide-polygons-into-n-number-of-groups-of-equal-counts-with-arcgis-10-2/132393#132393

Comment: @FelixIP that's a question I posted that isn't quite the same thing as what is being asked here, if I'm understanding Alinaa's question correctly. My question doesn't incorporate shared boundaries.

Comment: Approach is exactly the same. It includes very minor change in spatial join setup to create what I call links table. If she is talking about something similar to your illustration simple dissolve with no case field will do.

Comment: @EmilBrungade forgot the hash

Answer (score 1):

Making use of feature layers, selections, and a `while` loop to select neighboring features until no new features are selected is the way to go, if you just want to cluster all features that touch together. The script below adds a field and updates it with a cluster number. The clusters represent all touching features.

```
import arcpy

#In feature class
fc = r"C:\Users\Emil\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\testpolygon"

#New cluster field name
fieldname = "Group"

#Add field
arcpy.AddField_management (fc, fieldname, "SHORT")

#Make feature layer to allow for selection
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, "lyr")

#Get layer OID field name for use in SQL
OIDfieldName = arcpy.Describe ("lyr").OIDFieldName

#Create list for OIDs that have been selected
allselectedOIDs = []

#Variable to designate clusters
Cluster = 1

#cursor to iterate through features
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("lyr", "OID@")
for row in cursor:

    #Check if OID has been selected and assigned to a cluster
    if row[0] in allselectedOIDs:
        #skip iteration
        continue

    #SQL to select single feature
    sql = '"{0}" = {1}'.format (OIDfieldName, row[0])

    #Set old selection count to 0
    OldSelectionCount = 0

    #Select feature
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "", sql)

    #set new selection count to 1
    NewSelectionCount = 1

    #While loop 
    while NewSelectionCount != OldSelectionCount:

        #Update old selection count
        OldSelectionCount = NewSelectionCount

        #Select neighbors
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management ("lyr", "", "lyr")

        #Get new selection count
        NewSelectionCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lyr").getOutput(0))

    #Get list of selected feature OIDs with list comprehension
    selectedOIDs = [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("lyr", "OID@")]

    #Add selected feature OIDs to all OIDs list
    allselectedOIDs += selectedOIDs 

    #Update layer field with cluster number
    arcpy.CalculateField_management ("lyr", fieldname, Cluster)

    print Cluster
    #Add 1 to cluster variable
    Cluster += 1

#Clean up
del row
del cursor
```

Results:
[image: Clusters]

I hope this is along the lines of what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers..
**Done that using this script**

```
# 1.a   Checking Polygon is Touching or not
                    polys = []  
                    selected_polygon = []
                    rowcount = 0  
                    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Census_data","Shape@") as cursor:
                            for row in cursor:
                                polys.append(row[0])
                                rowcount = rowcount + 1
                    if(rowcount >= 1):
                            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Census_data","Shape@") as cursor:
                                for row in cursor:  
                                    selected_polygon.append(row[0])

                            for i in range(len(selected_polygon)):  
                                overlap = 0  
                                for j in range(len(polys)):  
                                    if selected_polygon[i].distanceTo(polys[j]) == 0:  
                                        overlap = overlap + 1  
                                if overlap >= 1:  
                                    print ("Touching")

                                else:
                                    print ("Not Touching")
                                    break
```

Comment: Why is Aggregate Polygons http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000000s000000 with a *very* small tolerance not suitable? I think the word you wanted was Contiguous (close together) not Contagious (like a disease you catch) - damn spellcheck! I usually use Dissolve followed by Multipart to Single Part to turn clusters into larger polygons but the boundaries must be exactly the same or they wont dissolve, the Aggregate will be more forgiving about very close vs shared boundary.