# Split polygons based on raster layer and defined target size

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, splitting

[image: polygon split]

I have polygons with interpolated data like on the picture on right.

Now I want to split this polygon into smaller polygons with predefined similar area. Positions of these smaller polygons must be based on value from interpolated data below. So one smaller polygon should contains area with values for example 1-10.

Result should look like picture on the left.

Does anyone can help me or give idea how to do this in QGIS, python, R, javascript or any other GIS Software?

Answer (score 1):

I placed 3000 regularly spaced points inside polygon similar to your uppermost :

[image]

And applied method and script described in
[Graph/Network building and analysis of linked polygons in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop/153348#153348)

attempting to split polygon into 25 ‘equal’ area bits.

Result:

[image]

Note polygons labeled by their area.

I think you can get very close to your goal by applying technique mentioned.

Comment: you could use voronoi polygons on the points. i think that would result in more 'regular' shapes.

Comment: On what points? I have to pick 25 out of 3000

Comment: My comment was with regard to the 3000 points. The same principle could be applied regardless of the number of points used, provided they are regularly spaced.

Comment: Good idea!  I am going to test it

Comment: I was thinking also about voronoi polygons. But clue is that this polygons should be in location based on value.  As you can see in my picture on the left, one polygon is on the dark area and one on the light area. There is no polygons that half is on dark and half is on light.

Other thing - is it possible to define excepted area of voronoi polygons?