# QGIS polygon features split by area

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a shapefile with 10,000 polygon features in QGIS I want each polygon to be split into multiple polygons features (partitioning whole polygon area) using some attribute value say NoOfPartions. I am using QGIS for same but there doesn't seem any way to do so for all features. Manually clipping is not feasible due to large number of features.

Is there any possible way to do so in QGIS/PyQgis?

Comment: Are there any spatial requirements as to how the polygons need to be split? Area of partitions, percent of whole, ect.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171727/polygon-split-with-defined-area?rq=1

Comment: #Kingfisher
there is as such no constraint w.r.t split.
I simply need whole area of polygon to be divided as an attribute value which defines no of partitions .
area of splitted partitions can be any random value.

Comment: #underdark
I am looking for some open source solution only.
So, preferably QGIS , python combination or any other open source tool would be helpful