# Creating Polygons Based on Point Count in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, count, planning

I am looking to create polygons based on a point count, and hopefully find a way to automate this too. My example is, I have 1,000 points in my city boundary and I want to create polygons over the area of 100 people in the city boundary. So my result would be 10 polygons each covering a 100 people and not overlapping. I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 with an Advanced level license.

I couldn't find the answer online.

I would want to automate this too so I could do this multiple times as the population grows.

I don't want to go by distance I want to go by point count alone.

Comment: There's probably many different permutations for populating a working set of polygons which meet this criteria.  The problem may even be [NP complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).  The task is similar to redistricting, which would still be difficult if the politicians didn't want to choose their voters.

Comment: Redistricting is what I am after, luckily its for a school district's new schools and not a politician selecting voters. Any Suggestions?

Comment: If you don't think politics is involved when a kid doesn't get assigned to the school in their backyard, then you don't understand redistricting.

Comment: If you take a numbers and staffing approach you cut out the politics. This is why I gave the city example, because the second you mention school district everyone tends to lose their mind.

Answer (score 7):

INPUTS:
[image]

Proceed with technique I described multiple times, e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop/153348#153348)

RESULT:

[image]

NOTE:
Multiple solutions possible

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the Information, that really helps.