# How can I create a grid overlay that accounts for feature density instead of map unit area?

Tags: arcgis-pro, grids-graticules

I am working with the below spatial data (each point does contain relevant attribute information). I need to be able to audit these data for completeness and accuracy against the associated data from a CRM system. To this point, I have performed several attribute and spatial analyses to identify and add or eliminate a large portion duplicate or inaccurate records. However, I am still finding several areas that points or attributes are missing or inaccurate. From here, my only option left, given the poor structure of the data, is to individually verify points and clean up data.

**WHAT I AM HOPING TO ACCOMPLISH:**

> I would like to create a grid for this data set that will break down the spatial data into blocks of 100-200 points to help systematically review the the existing data and the surrounding area for any points that may be missing.

**SOFTWARE:**

> I am currently working in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 with a basic license. I do have access to QGIS as well if needed, however I would like to find a way within Pro to complete this task.

[image]

Comment: You could tessellate the grid (break cells with more than 200 features into quarters, then repeat as necessary).  I've written ArcPy code for geodesic equal-area rectangles (fixed width, variable height, with ten levels of tessellation (from 25 sq km down to 1.56 and  up to up to 409600 km^2). This should be easy enough to accomplish with two or three levels in a projected coordinate system (three fishnets and some spatial queries).

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250113/clustering-neighboring-points-inside-arcgis-desktop#250230