# Clustering points into *n* number of groups of equal counts with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clustering, grouping

I have to  divide points into groups. These groups will be used by agents to talk to property owners. The goal is to make the agent's job easy by grouping parcels that are near each other together, as well as divide the parcels into (almost) equal numbers so that the work is distributed evenly. The number of agents is variable: from 2 to 8.

I've explored various ArcGIS tools (Grouping analysis and Distriction), but none seem to suit my need.

Is there a reliable method to do this task?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop, QGIS, PostGIS, SAGA or any other open source solution you wish to ask about in this question.  By asking about multiple software products you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour] which says that there should be one question asked per question.

Comment: Automation is only as reliable as your code. Without code, there isn't any way to answer.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173412/creating-polygons-based-on-point-count-in-arcgis-for-desktop/173430#173430