# Grouping point data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have about 1600 fire hydrants that I need to divide in to groups of 10 by nearest neighbor, this process will be used to send out crews to conduct hydrant inspections. I have tried using the Grouping Analysis tool but an error reads no variation in any of the Analysis Fields.

Comment: What precisely did you try and what was the exact error?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop/153348#153348 method and script applicable to any geometry

Answer (score 1):

You can create two new fields in your hydrants feature class attribute table, populating them with the x and y coordinates of your hydrant points. Then use both of these as your analysis fields within the Grouping Analysis tool.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I ran the tool with these fields and had it set to 160 groups hoping that it would divide the hydrants equally. The tool did select hydrants in close proximity but didn't divide them into equally sized groups.