# Spatial Analysis Grouping/Clustering Question

Tags: clustering, spatial-analysis, arcgis-local-government

If this question is incorrectly titled, I apologize; I wasn't sure exactly how to best phrase it. I'm working with my city's housing department to develop zones for building inspectors. One of the attributes of each building footprint/polygon is total building square footage. The department is requesting that I find a way to group all the buildings into zones that have roughly equivalent total square footage. I briefly looked into Grouping Analysis and Location-Allocation, but I'm not sure either of those is what I am looking for. IIRC from graduate school, ESRI does have a tool for this, but it's been almost 10 years since graduate school.

Is there such a tool, or am I remembering incorrectly?

If not, could anyone suggest a good way to do this?

Spatial statistics and analysis are not really my strong suit.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop/153348#153348 and my multiple other answers on this topic