# Clustering by Equal Sum Value

Tags: python, clustering

I have a shapefile of points that each have a value A. I want to be able to create cluster regions such that if I sum value A for each point in a region, the sum of value A for each region will be equal.

Is there a way I can solve this problem with ArcPy or cluster analysis? It seems that most clustering solutions are focused on finding areas of high, low, or similar values rather than a statistic of each cluster.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop/153348#153348