# Group cells of a polygon grid based on reciprocal distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a polygon square grid 5x5km, clipped with admin boundaries. I want to create contiguous groups of cells (clusters) of almost equal area, minimizing the distance of each cell from the center of the cluster.
I have tried Spatial Statistics > Mapping Clusters > Grouping analysis in ArcGIS but I do not understand how to set the parameter, and it does not work as I need. I get this type of results.

[image]

I wish to have an equal size cluster with spatial constraint. In this case with 2 clusters, but similar to the below example with 4:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? What is it about it that does not work?

Comment: Please decide whether it’s ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap, QGIS or R that you wish to ask about in this particular question. You currently have tags covering all of them as well as ArcPy but your question has no code.

Comment: I decided for Arcmap.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example image of what your output should look like (can be a crude sketch), it's not clear to exactly what you want?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcmap