# Clustering Algorithms for Geospatial Data

Tags: algorithm, clustering

I am new to the world of Geospatial Analysis!

I am interested in learning about Clustering Algorithms that can be used for Geospatial Data.

For instance, suppose I have:

- A shapefile for all ZIP Codes in California (this contains information on which ZIP codes share borders with other ZIP codes)
- A data frame that contains information on which ZIP Code a person lives in and how many COVID vaccines this person has taken (e.g. John lives in ZIP Code 90211 and has 2 vaccines, Sally also lives in 90211 and has 4 vaccines, James lives in ZIP Code 90212 and has 0 vaccines, etc.).

**I would like to run a Clustering Algorithm on this data to find out which groups of ZIP Codes have similar vaccination rates.**

In the past, I would have just created variables with Longitude and Latitude belonging to the centroid of each ZIP code, and then run a clustering algorithm like K-Means (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) on this data ( 3 columns : longitude, latitude, number of vaccine - "n" rows ).

However, I was wondering if there might be a "better" way to go about this task. For example, suppose I want the resulting clusters to physically "touch" each other (left) and not to be "disjoint" (right) and use the "border" information within the shapefile (e.g. treating the shapefile as a network graph):

[image]

Are there some specific types of clustering algorithms that are well suited for this kind of problem? The approach that I described can infer these boundaries using long/lat ... but is there some clustering algorithm that can make use of the common boundaries?

**Note**: Example of Data

| names | zip | long | lat | number_of_vaccines |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 alex | 90211 | 118.3842 | 34.0661 | 5 |
| 2 tim | 90211 | 118.3842 | 34.0661 | 0 |
| 3 paul | 90212 | 118.4017 | 34.0617 | 1 |

Desired Output:

| names | zip | long | lat | number_of_vaccines | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | 90211 | 118.3842 | 34.0661 | 5 |
| 2 | tim | 90211 | 118.3842 | 34.0661 | 0 |
| 3 | paul | 90212 | 118.4017 | 34.0617 | 1 |

Comment: Question is unclear: are you asking how to create points in the zip-code polygons? Are you asking about how to count the number of points in each zip-code polygon? What is your problem: zip-code areas you have are not touching each other?

Comment: @ Babel: hello! I am just looking for a general approach to cluster zip codes together such that they form clusters with similar vaccination rates.

Comment: Your data comes as points? Try Voronoi polygons

Comment: @ babel: thank you! I will look into this?

Comment: Clustering is a hot topic in ML. If you can assign a position to all data records you can use for example DBSCAN to find clusters.

Comment: @ zoltan: thank you for your reply! I am aware of DBSCAN  ... but I was just wondering if there are some special types of clustering algorithms that can take advantage of the polygon boundaries within the shapefile?

Comment: See if this helps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153094/graph-network-building-and-analysis-of-linked-polygons-in-arcmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The R implementation of the GEODA software has several options that will cluster using contingency. A 1st order polygon contiguity is defined as the polygons touching each given polygon.

Here is a rundown of some examples. Each model results in a list object containing the cluster results and other attributes, eg., sum of squares, p-values, depending on the given algorithm. To assign and visualize results simply assign the objects cluster vector (ie., x$Clusters) to the source data.

```
library(sf)
library(rgeoda)

guerry <- st_read(system.file("extdata", "Guerry.shp", package = "rgeoda"))
  guerry <- guerry[c('Crm_prs','Crm_prp','Litercy','Donatns','Infants','Suicids','Pop1831')]
```

Create the 1st order contiguity matrix (Wij)

```
wij <- queen_weights(guerry, order=1)
```

Spatial C(K)luster Analysis by Tree Edge Removal(SKATER) algorithm (Assuncao et al. 2006) using a minimum spanning tree. Here we have an example of assigning cluster results back to the spatial object and plotting.

```
( skater.clust <- skater(4, wij, guerry) )
  guerry$skater_clust <- skater.clust$Clusters
    plot(guerry["skater_clust"])
```

[image: cluster results]

REDCAP (Regionalization with dynamically constrained agglomerative clustering and partitioning) using single-linkage, average-linkage, and the complete-linkage spaning trees (D. Guo 2008)

```
( redcap.clust <- redcap(4, wij, guerry, "fullorder-completelinkage") )
```

Automatic zoning procedure (AZP) was initially outlined in Openshaw (1977) as a way to address some of the consequences of the modifiable areal unit problem (MAUP). The second example uses simulated annealing

```
( azp.clust <- azp_greedy(5, wij, guerry) )
( azp.saclust <- azp_sa(5, wij, guerry, cooling_rate = 0.85) )
```

The max-p regions model (Duque et al., 2012) considers the regionalization problem as an application of integer programming. It has the advantage of not require definition of k (number of clusters). This is a spatial optimization approach akin to MARXAN and requires a population field that is used for the optimization and is one of the few available approaches that accounts for allocation of a variable across the cluster soultion. In this case simulated annealing is used for optimizing clusters to have a population ~3236.

```
bound_vals <- guerry['Pop1831']
min_bound <- 3236.67 # 10% of Pop1831
( maxp.saclust <- maxp_sa(wij, guerry, bound_vals, min_bound, 
                      cooling_rate=0.85, sa_maxit=1) )
```

Answer (score 2):

The "traditional" clustering methods (like k-means or HCA) cannot do efficiently what you want. Adding X and Y coordinates like variables to classify can work, but it is quite uncertain.

There are however some variations of these algorithms, with  a spatial constraint. The idea is the following: each time an individual is added to a class, the algorithm check that it validates a fixed spatial constraint (based on the distance or the topology).

I know of two tools that can perform this type of clustering: [ClustGeo,](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustGeo/vignettes/intro_ClustGeo.html) an R package that can perform a spatially constrained HCA and [GeoDa.](https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/9d_spatial4/lab9d.html)

Answer (score 2):

To some extent you can achieve multi-dimensional clustering with 2-dimensionally restricted (i.e. coordinates) cluster-algorithms, given that you can coerce your other values into a single numeric surrogate to be used as bounds of some sort - a pre-clustering.

For example, rank your similarity - round the vaccination rates to multiples of any static factor - and run a simple spatial proximity cluster algorithm (i.e. cluster by adjacency) using the bin values as bounds (i.e. cluster geometries within the same bin only, for each bin).

The obvious advantage of a simple workaround like this is that it's applicable in many geospatial frameworks. And that its *simple*. *KISS*!

The main disadvantage is the lack of flexibility with regards to bin ranges - they are fixed, and while you can find clever ways to delineate bins and/or iterate the above approach (re-bin, re-cluster, repeat) until you're satisfied, there's no way to benefit from actual statistical corellation across your similarity like you could using e.g. matrix-based algorithms.

---

To give a simple example in PostgreSQL/PostGIS SQL:

```
SELECT
  zip.id,
  ST_ClusterDBSCAN(zip.geom, 0, 1)
    OVER( PARTITION BY (zip.vaccinations / <factor>)::INT ) AS cid
FROM
  <zip_geoms_with_vaccination_counts>
;
```

The DBSCAN itself here mainly serves the purpose of clustering by spatial adjacency - the mentioned workaround is baked in via the `PARTITION BY` statement, effectively saying *consider adjacency only between geometries of the same bin*.