# Create groups according to spatial contiguity?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a large set of points for school sites and I want to divide these schools into 6 groups, for example, and I want each group to consist of 200 schools, provided they are spatially close to each other.

How can I do that in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250113/clustering-neighboring-points-inside-arcgis-desktop

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131841/dividing-polygons-into-n-number-of-groups-of-equal-counts-with-arcpy

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting overlapping polygons from one Shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119439/counting-overlapping-polygons-from-one-shapefile-using-arcgis-desktop)